# HTTP POST Failure in Cordova using Visual Studio

Tags: php, jquery, cordova, visual-studio-2012

I've been trying to get a simple HTTP POST to work to connect a cordova based application to server(php based).

I've coded up a simple php file just for the testing purpose.

Php Code:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["TEST"])){
        echo "TEST WORKS!!";
    }
?>
```

Now the jquery code in my cordova application>

```
// For an introduction to the Blank template, see the following documentation:
// http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397704
// To debug code on page load in Ripple or on Android devices/emulators: launch your app, set breakpoints, 
// and then run "window.location.reload()" in the JavaScript Console.
(function () {
    "use strict";

    document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);

    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Handle the Cordova pause and resume events
        document.addEventListener('pause', onPause.bind(this), false);
        document.addEventListener('resume', onResume.bind(this), false);

        // TODO: Cordova has been loaded. Perform any initialization that requires Cordova here.
        //My Code
        $('#btnSend').on('click', function () {

            $.post('http://mobtest.bugs3.com/test.php',
                { TEST: 'TEST' },
                function (result) {
                    alert(result);
                    $('#txtlbl').text(result);
                },
                function (error) {
                    alert(error);
                    $('#txtlbl').text(error);
                }
            );

        });
    };

    function onPause() {
        // TODO: This application has been suspended. Save application state here.
    };

    function onResume() {
        // TODO: This application has been reactivated. Restore application state here.
    };
})();
```

This is built on the template provided by visual studio for apache/cordova build.

When I click the button, I see the following message in my console :

```
http://localhost:4400/ripple/xhr_proxy?tinyhippos_apikey=ABC&tinyhippos_rurl=http%3A//mobtest.bugs3.com/test.php Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Where the `http://mobtest.bugs3.com/test.php`

is the url of the php file.

*EDIT*

After a bit of research, I've figured out that it's the CROSS DOMAIN PROXY, that's causing the problem.

Now the latest error message is :

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://mobtest.bugs3.com/test.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4414' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Looking for some help on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem.
When using the RIPPLE Emulator, SETTINGS->CROSS DOMAIN PROXY = REMOTE

Other-wise cross domain requests are blocked.

Answer (score 5):

Found the answer [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757052.aspx). Change the **Cross Domain Proxy** setting to **"Remote"** or **"Disabled"**. By default it is set to "Local" which doesn't allow cross domain resource access.

[image]